# Ansible: Can I execute role from command line?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Suppose I have a role called "apache"

Now I want to execute that role on host 192.168.0.10 from the command line from Ansible host

```
ansible-playbook -i  "192.168.0.10" --role  "path to role"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 117):

With ansible 2.7 you can do this:

```
$ ansible localhost --module-name include_role --args name=<role_name>
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "include_variables": {
        "name": "<role_name>"
    }
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "<role_name>"
}
```

This will run role from /path/to/ansible/roles or configured role path.

Read more here:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/43131

Comment: This does not really answer the question because there's no reference to the external role YAML file @kari implemented and wants to include. I have the same question. Yet after reading this answer, I only understand that it is feasible. I just don't know how.

Comment: Hopefully I have clarified the answer @Kola

Comment: This is broken in Ansible 2.8. It just logs cryptic error messages like `'ERROR! 'async_val' is not a valid attribute for a IncludeRole'.`

Comment: This solution seems to work for me with ansible 2.8.2. It does seem to have a problem with exposing variables to other roles included within the original role (which is not a problem in a playbook). I tried changing to `-a "name=<role_name> public=yes"`, but that didn't help.

Comment: To understand what -m and -a does see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/modules_intro.html
Basically, this is how modules can be started from command line (`-m <module-name>`) with key=value pairs as arguments (`-a key=value`)

Comment: one caveat is that ad-hoc cli commands don't have access to the `ansible_facts` which the role might need. To work around it, you can use caching: `ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN=jsonfile ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN_CONNECTION=/tmp/ansible-cache ansible -m setup yourHostname` and then `ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN=jsonfile ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN_CONNECTION=/tmp/ansible-cache ansible -m include_role .....`

Answer (score 107):

I am not aware of this feature, but you can use tags to just run one role from your playbook.

```
roles:
    - {role: 'mysql', tags: 'mysql'}
    - {role: 'apache', tags: 'apache'}

ansible-playbook webserver.yml --tags "apache"
```

Answer (score 26):

There is no such thing in Ansible, but if this is an often use case for you, try this script.
Put it somewhere within your searchable PATH under name `ansible-role`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 2 ]]; then
  cat <<HELP
Wrapper script for ansible-playbook to apply single role.

Usage: $0 <host-pattern> <role-name> [ansible-playbook options]

Examples:
  $0 dest_host my_role
  $0 custom_host my_role -i 'custom_host,' -vv --check
HELP
  exit
fi

HOST_PATTERN=$1
shift
ROLE=$1
shift

echo "Trying to apply role \"$ROLE\" to host/group \"$HOST_PATTERN\"..."

export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH="$(pwd)/roles"
export ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED="False"
ansible-playbook "$@" /dev/stdin <<END
---
- hosts: $HOST_PATTERN
  roles:
    - $ROLE
END
```

Comment: I have created a "create an ansible-role" tool proposal, we will see: https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/131

Comment: Looks like it's been implemented in Ansible 2.7: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/43131

Comment: Yes, please try `ansible localhost -m include_role -a name=myrole` - works for me!

Comment: `ansible localhost -m include_role -a name=myrole` is broken since ansible 2.8. It just logs cryptic error messages like `'ERROR! 'async_val' is not a valid attribute for a IncludeRole'.`

Comment: This was re-fixed in [cd95843](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/cd95843ea5f1bff40225b0430cfbb379cbe53661)

Answer (score 18):

You could also check [ansible-toolbox](https://github.com/larsks/ansible-toolbox) repository. It will allow you to use something like

```sh
ansible-role --host 192.168.0.10 --gather --user centos --become my-role
```

Answer (score 17):

I have written a small Ansible plugin, called `auto_tags`, that dynamically generates for each role in your playbook a tag of the same name. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/rkrzr/f5387167fa7b4869e2dca8b713879562).

After installing it (instructions are in the gist above) you could then execute a specific role with:

`ansible-playbook -i  "192.168.0.10" --tags "name_of_role"`

Answer (score 5):

Since in ansible 2.4 two options are available: `import_role` and `include_role`.

```
wohlgemuth@leela:~/workspace/rtmtb-ansible/kvm-cluster$ ansible localhost -m import_role -a name=rtmtb
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

localhost | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "d31b41e68997e1c7f182bb56286edf993146dba1", 
    "dest": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.github", 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "md5sum": "b7831c4c72f3f62207b2b96d3d7ed9b3", 
    "mode": "0600", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "size": 3389, 
    "src": "/home/wohlgemuth/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561491049.46-139127672211209/source", 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}
localhost | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "1972ebcd25363f8e45adc91d38405dfc0386b5f0", 
    "dest": "/root/.ssh/config", 
    "gid": 0, 
    "group": "root", 
    "md5sum": "f82552a9494e40403da4a80e4c528781", 
    "mode": "0644", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "size": 147, 
    "src": "/home/wohlgemuth/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561491049.99-214274671218454/source", 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 0
}
```

[ansible.builtin.import_role – Import a role into a play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html)

[ansible.builtin.include_role – Load and execute a role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-include-role-module)

Comment: But no facts are gathered, so this is not equivalent to using a playbook.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried that? it's super cool. I'm using 'update-os' instead of 'apache' role to give a more meaningful example. I have a role called let's say `./roles/update-os/` in my `./` I add a file called `./role-update-os.yml` which looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ansible-playbook
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
  - update-os
```

Make this file executable (`chmod +x role-update-os.yml`). Now you can run and limit to whatever you have in your inventory `./update-os.yml -i inventory-dev --limit 192.168.0.10` the limit you can pass the group names as well.

- `--limit web,db` > web and db is the group defined in your inventory
- `--limit 192.168.0.10,192.168.0.201`

```
$ cat inventory-dev
[web]
192.168.0.10

[db]
192.168.0.201
```

Note that you can configure ssh-keys and sudoers policy to be able to execute without having to type password - ideal for automation, there are security implications with this. therefore you have to analyze your environment to see whether it's suitable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `import_role` is an ansible module and as such it may be invoked through `ansible` command. The following executes role `pki` on `my_server`

```
ansible my_server -m import_role \
                  -a "name=pki tasks_from=gencert" \
                  -e cn=etcdctl \
                  -e extended_key_usage=clientAuth
```

Comment: As a caveat, note that while this invocation works, it will *not* implicitly gather facts; so, if you have a role with a task that references something like `ansible_date_time`, this invocation will fail. I'm not sure if there's a workaround to that; it seems like you'd just need to use an 'entry-point' playbook instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the playbook files from the command line:

1. Install the role (if not already installed)

   ```
   ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/user/apache-role.git
   ```
2. Create playbook and hosts files

   ```
   cat >> playbook.yml <<EOL
   ---
   - name: Run apache
     hosts: all
     roles:
       - apache-role
   EOL

   cat >> hosts <<EOL
   192.168.0.10
   EOL
   ```
3. Run ansible

   ```
   ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts
   ```
4. Delete the files

   ```
   rm playbook.yml hosts
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell one-liner:

> `printf -- "- hosts: localhost\n  roles:\n    - myrole\n" | ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local /dev/stdin`

To run on a specific IP, replace localhost with your host.