# Ansible-playbook run against arbitrary host which is not in inventory file and include group vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

When I run a playbook `runrole.yml` this way:

```
ansible-playbook -i '192.168.0.7,' runrole.yml -e "ROLE=allwindows" -e "TARGETIP=192.168.0.7" -e "ansible_port=5986" --ask-vault-pass
```

`runrole.yml` has:

```
- hosts:  '{{TARGETIP}}'
  roles:
  - { role: '{{ROLE}}' }
```

It works (i.e. it runs against 192.168.0.7), but it fails because I have not provided all additional arguments

```
ansible_user: Administrator
ansible_password: SecretPasswordGoesHere
ansible_connection: winrm
```

I would like Ansible to use variables which are defined in `group-vars/allwindows.yml`.

It will work, If I add into inventory file into a group `[allwindows]` host `192.168.0.7`:

```
[allwindows]
host1
...
hostN
192.168.0.7
```

and run using:

```
ansible-playbook runrole.yml -e "ROLE=allwindows" -e "TARGETIP=192.168.0.7" -e "ansible_port=5986" --ask-vault-pass
```

It works fine as it detects that `192.168.0.7` belongs to a group `allwindows`.
In certain scenarios I would like to run a role against a host without touching the inventory file. How do I specify to include group `allwindows` to use all variables from `group_vars/allwindows.yml` without modifying the inventory file?

Comment: There're some steps which are not needed. I have to create a file, add some content into it run a command and delete that file. If I won't delete that file I would have to review it when I do commit into repository.
Ideally I would like to run just a line without doing all those extra steps.

Comment: Take a look at this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38419466/2795592)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I don't have an issue with running a role. The issue with running a role against a node which is not in the inventory file. I believe your solution will have same problem as eventually it is doing same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a hack how to do that. It is not nice as @techraf's answer but it  works with ansible-playbook

```
ATARGETIP=192.168.0.7 && echo "[allwindows]" > tmpinventory && echo "$ATARGETIP" >> tmpinventory && ansible-playbook -i tmpinventory runrole.yml -e "ROLE=allwindows" -e "TARGETIP=$ATARGETIP" -e "ansible_port=5986" --ask-vault-pass && rm tmpinventory
```