# ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH cannot assume to get correct role in bash script

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

From [Ansible: Can I execute role from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350674/ansible-can-i-execute-role-from-command-line) -

```
HOST_PATTERN=$1
shift
ROLE=$1
shift

echo "To apply role \"$ROLE\" to host/group \"$HOST_PATTERN\"..."

export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH="$(pwd)/roles"
export ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED="False"

ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH="$(pwd)/roles" ansible-playbook "$@" /dev/stdin <<END
---
- hosts: $HOST_PATTERN
  roles:
    - $ROLE
END
```

Problem is when I run with `./apply.sh all dev-role -i dev-inventory`, it cannot assume the correct role. When I run with `ansible-playbook -i dev-inventory site.yml --tags dev-role`, it's working.

Below is error message

```
fatal: [my-api]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum_dest": null, "checksum_src": "d3a0ae8f3b45a0a7906d1be7027302a8b5ee07a0", "dest": "/tmp/install-amazon2-td-agent4.sh", "elapsed": 0, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0644", "msg": "Destination /tmp/install-amazon2-td-agent4.sh is not writable", "owner": "root", "size": 838, "src": "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1600788856.749975-487-237398580935180/tmpobyegc", "state": "file", "uid": 0, "url": "https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-amazon2-td-agent4.sh"}
```

Comment: `dev-rol` != `dev-role`

Comment: You will get more help if you define what "it cannot assume the correct role" means in your specific case; there are exactly zero error messages or log lines in your question

Comment: @mdaniel I've added error message.

Comment: @PaulHodges it's my typo. I've fixed.

Comment: The error seems to be `Destination /tmp/install-amazon2-td-agent4.sh is not writable`,  That should be the first thing to check.

Comment: @larsks when I run `ansible-playbook -i dev-inventory site.yml --tags dev-role` it's working.

Comment: I'd guess `site.yml` contains `become: yes` whereas your `/dev/stdin` version does not

Comment: @mdaniel perfect...!!! Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `"msg": "Destination /tmp/install-amazon2-td-agent4.sh is not writable"`, I'd guess it is because `site.yml` contains `become: yes` statement, which makes all tasks run as `root`. The "anonymous" playbook does not contain a `become:` declaration, and thus would need one to either run `ansible-playbook --become` or to add `become: yes` to it, also

```sh
ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH="$(pwd)/roles" ansible-playbook "$@" /dev/stdin <<END
---
- hosts: $HOST_PATTERN
  become: yes
  roles:
    - $ROLE
END
```

Comment: can you also help me to check my another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021309/kubernetes-container-name-got-null-in-fluentdconfiguration