# How to do a step sleep in the Ansible playbook execution?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook command, which is to set up a k8s cluster, but it fails sometime, as some dependent pieces are not quick enough to be ready, for its follow-ups.

So instead, I am think to have this command execute step by step, something as if:

```
yes | ansible-playbook ... --step
```

but how may I have a delay, in between each step execution during which.
Thanks,

Jack

Comment: what have you tried so far? is it failing? have you looked into Ansible's module `wait_for` or `pause`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a fairly complicated job, that contains lots of tasks, I have not figured out a way to use these settings.  So is there a way doing it on command line level ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> ***How to do a step sleep in the `ansible-playbook` execution? ... I have not figured out a way to use these settings. ...***

You may have a look into [`pause`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html) module and following example

```yaml
- name: Make sure service has time to start or stop
  pause:
    seconds: 60
  when: not ansible_check_mode
```

> *I am think to have this command execute step by step ...*

Or in other words task by task. Therefore you may have a look into [Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html) as with them one will have the capability to execute single tasks or groups of tasks, depending on tags used.

**Further Q&A**

- [How to run only one task in Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945201/)

---

Regarding `--step` and

> ***... in between each step execution during which ...***

please take note that [Step mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_startnstep.html#step-mode) is mentioned to [Executing playbooks for troubleshooting](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_startnstep.html)

> *With this option, Ansible stops on each task, and asks if it should execute that task.*

Regarding

> ***... but how may I have a delay ...***

There is already a delay in that approach, the user. Since the next task will only execute if the user press yes.